# Issues with touchpad indicator

Tags: touchpad

Touchpad indicator is a lifesaver. However, there are several problems with that. Each time I unplug my mouse it doesn't reenable the touchpad. I have hit the shortcut keys to first disable and then hit it again to Also each time I shut the lid down on my laptop it disables the touchpad even if the touchpad was enabled before.reenable. And then to get the effect of disabling the touchpad while typing. I have to go to preferences and click 'OK', exit the touchpad-indicator and restart it again. Anyway to fix this problem.  What would be the command to restart the touchpad-indicator?

System Information
    Manufacturer: LENOVO
    Product Name: 20ENCTO1WW
    Version: ThinkPad P50

Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: I am neither psychic nor a mind reader and I don't like guessing games.  What is your hardware (PC/laptop with model number) and Operating System? Please [edit] the question and include this essential information.

Comment: See an answer on ask ubuntu site: <https://askubuntu.com/questions/879511/issues-with-touchpad-indicator/906930>